# Second order non-homogeneous differential equation where g(x) is a constant - how to determine particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is somewhat silly but I'm struggling to obtain the particular solution of the following differential equation:

$y"+(\frac{1}{x})y'=1$

I know how to get the complementary solution. I even got particular solution by direct integration in one of the earlier steps of the derivation ($y_p=\frac{x^2}{4}$). But I don't know how to do it by using the method of undetermined coefficients. I tried polynomial of order 0 but I get incorrect solution.

I would appreciate any help or hint.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+\frac{1}{x}y'=1$$
$$x^2y''+xy'=x^2$$
It's Cauchy- Euler's equation you can transform it to a DE with constant coefficients then apply undetermined coeffcients ((substitute  $x=e^t$).
$$\implies y''(t)=e^{2t}$$
Then try $y_p(t)=Ae^{2t}$ or integrate directly

---

Another method:
$$x^2y''+xy'=x^2$$
try $y=x^m$ for the homogeneous equation
$$m(m-1)+m=0 \implies m=0$$
$$ \implies y=c_1+c_2 \ln x$$
For the particular solution try $y_p(x)=Ax^2$